# why is flatulence forbidden in tefillin and during prayer

Tags: tefilla, halacha-theory, tefilin, bathroom

Why is flatulence forbidden in Tefillin and during prayer?

Is it because partials of the feces get stuck to the body so now you do not have a clean body?

or what?

Comment: What about simply: "It's impolite and inappropriate conduct while wearing an object as holy as Tefillin?"

Comment: As an aside, it likely isn't due to physical particals stuck to the body, for if that was the reason, you'd then need to wipe before continuing praying.

Comment: @Salmononius2 how do you know you do not need to? and why is it called a clean body (guf noki)?

Comment: AFAIK, no one mentions the requirement of needing to clean oneself before continuing prayer, while they do mention waiting for the smell to pass. I'm assuming that if cleaning was required, that would be mentioned too. You're right about the terminology 'Guf Naki', which seems to imply some sort of physical uncleanliness.

Comment: @Salmononius2 (first comment) So why isn't urination a problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA IIRC, you were historically not actually required to remove Tefillin when urinating, covering it was enough. Seemingly urinating wasn't considered as "disgusting" as flatulating.

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Ish Chai(Od Yosef Chai Chaye Sarah 4) says the problem is the bad smell. He therefore says one is allowed to pass gas if he knows it will not smell.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41237&st=&pgnum=19

Comment: It's an Od Yosef,but howe can one determine if it will produce a smell or not?

Comment: @Sam beautiful, thanks! I guess by his own words at the end there, everybody knows their personal nature.

Comment: From my understanding it seems he is saying that it's more of a b'deieved ,but I see where your coming from

Comment: I did have a question on his premise though. I'm quite certain there is a Gemara that refers to the passing of gas with a smell as an itush. I'll have to try to find that.