# Is there any benefit to an adult with the general mental capacity of a child of around 6 months wearing Tefillin?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, handicap-disabled-impair

I assume that an adult with the general mental capacity of a child of around 6 months is free from mitzvos. Would there be any benefit to (the neshomo of) this adult in getting his body to do mitzvos like tzitzis or tefillin asuming that his body was clean for the requisite period ?

Comment: Well there are lots of potential reasons why he "should." What is considered an important enough reason to be an acceptable answer to this question? Would the simple fact that he wants to do it count as a reason why he should? Maybe the simple fact that his parents want him to?

Comment: The question that you've asked is not really answerable. If there are particular reasons that you've heard why he "shouldn't" that you'd like to find rebuttals for, please include those here.  As it is, you're simply asking us to cherry-pick arguments that probably don't hold much weight on their own. I have voted to close this question for now. Assuming it does get closed, you can still edit the question to be clearer and then the question can be re-opened.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61864/1362 for why not.

Comment: I am not sure if this should be closed as really it's the kind of thing you should ask a rav? I have a son who is likely to be in the same situation. Now 10 years and 7 months old.

Comment: The obvious reason why he shouldn't is that he might let off wind as he would not know the significance of this prohibition.

Comment: some relevant discussion http://hearos.blogspot.com/2012/10/shabbos-30a-comatose-people-and-mitzvos.html

Comment: Each case is different. There can be a case in which he is physically unable but mentally capable of understanding and a case of being physically capable but mentally unable to understand what he is doing and all the variations along that spectrum. It should be closed as needing a psak from someone who understands the particular case.

Comment: I agree it should be closed for that reason, but I do not have enough rep to vote to close.

Comment: +1 This is a valid question asking for arguments given to support a Halachik opinion. Needing a psak from a Rav is not a reason to close. There can be many reasons the OP needs a Kulah in this matter.

Comment: @LN6595 Our job isn't to provide _kulot_. In any case, even if it was, we need to understand what the issue is in the first place. What are we trying to prove? The Torah says "וקשרתם לאות על ידך והיו לטטפת בין עיניך".  That sounds like a reason why someone "should" put _tefillin_ on. Is that a good enough reason for the OP? If not, why not? It doesn't address any potential issues with that person wearing _tefillin_ but the OP specifically says he/she doesn't care to hear about those issues.

Comment: I am not so sure it should be closed so quickly. I was looking into the discussion that Danno quoted. There is a conversation there about whether Mitzvos Tzrichos Kavvana. There may also be the concept of the Neshomo and that even someone who is both physcially unable to put on Tefilin and mentally unable to understand what he is doing nevertheless his Neshomo may benefit from the activity. I was wondering if anyone had some insight or source material to clarify this. I was't looking for a P'sak but rather insight and "reid".

Comment: Regarding Daniel's comment, I think that the Biblical verse isn't really a sufficient answer. Hence the Torah Shebaal Peh. I am aware of all the reasons why a person with his condition shouldn't put on Tefillin and it is these reasons that spur me to understand alternative opinions. And most importantly, if there are good reasons why he should, how can they override the obvious reasons that he shouldn't?

Comment: For numerous years, A *cheresh* was exempt from all mitzvoth, as in the time of the Gemarah, it was assumed that a *cheresh* was considered "unintelligent". For numerous years, there was a debate on exactly what *cheresh* meant, and the majority of recent (past 30 - 40 years) rulings have been that one who is deaf & uses sign-language is intelligent and is required to wear tefillin. I'm using this as a possible analogy to show that your case may be similar, if intelligence is a factor, here.

Comment: @DanF Which it's not. A Shoteh in the Gemara's terms is clearly exempt from all mitzvos. That doesn't mean he CAN'T do mitzvos, though.

Comment: I suggest you reword the question as below:

I assume that an adult with the general mental capacity of a child of around 6 months is free from mitzvos.

Would there be any benefit to (the neshomo of) this adult in getting his body to do mitzvos like tzitzis or tefillin asuming that his body was clean for the requisite period ?

Comment: @user2817 You may not like the answer about the _passuk_ (as I suspected you wouldn't). But the fact of the matter is, that answer would answer your question as currently worded. That's the entire reason the question is closed. It's not because there isn't an answer to the question you mean to ask. There may very well be good responses to the issues that you have alluded to. But if you don't mention which arguments you want refutations to, a trivial answer would work.

Comment: @Daniel  and others - please note edit to the question.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I think the edited version of the question has the same issue as the original version.

Comment: This depends on whether one view the mitzvos as theurgic rituals (as per the kabbalah) or as acts designed to improve man and society ethically and intellectually. (Rambam) if one adopts the latter view then it s certainly pointless to perform the act of a mitzva when it is not required and the performer is not aware. On the other hand, if one adopts the former view then it is conceivable that the act itself has supernatural implication. In this realm  it is not inconceivable that the act of one who is not required to perform a mitzvah, or aware of its performance, would achieve results.

Comment: a man with a profund mental disability is of course defined by Halacha as Shoyte. mitsvot has no sense for him, mitsvot are not theurgic rituals and not designed to improve etc. Mitsvot are mitsvot

Comment: @user2817 I beg that you and others do whatever you can to help this person, and especially this person, put on tefillin. I believe in the merit of this with my whole heart for reasons I cannot begin to explain. More compellingly, the Lubavitcher Rebbe emphatically believed that such people should do mitzvos l'maaseh, and wrote many letters on this topic. Please read them, and show them to your community, if possible: http://www.friendshipcircle.org/blog/2017/04/07/rebbe-approach-to-special-needs/

Comment: @user2817 I also think there is some merit in considering how much--or little--we *really* know about what these people perceive.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing sounds like the halachos category known as a "shoteh," a mentally disabled person, who, as you correctly assumed, is not obligated in mitzvos.

At first glance, you might point out that one still gains reward for doing mitzvos in which he or she is not obligated in, albeit less than that which a sane person gets (Kiddushin 31).

However, this isn't entirely true. The reason a deaf-mute, minor, and crazy person are not obligated in mitzvos is because of their lack of da'as, knowledge of what they're doing. It's for this reason that if they were to light Menorah, they wouldn't be accomplishing anything (Shabbos 23a), that they can't take Terumah (Mishnah Terumos 1:1), that one who sends a fire in their hand is only morally responsible but can't be held liable in Beis Din (BK 59b), etc. Thus, it would seem that they wouldn't be accomplishing anything by putting on Tefillin and Tzitzis.

This Halacha is said more explicitly in Erchin (2b):

> הכל חייבין בציצית לאיתויי מאי לאיתויי קטן היודע להתעטף דתניא קטן היודע להתעטף חייב בציצית הכל חייבין בתפילין לאיתויי מאי לאיתויי קטן היודע לשמור תפלין דתניא קטן היודע לשמור תפלין אביו לוקח לו תפלין
>
> "All are obligated in Tzitzis" - ["all"] comes to include what? To include a minor who is able to wrap ... "All are obligated in Tefillin" - ["all"] comes to include what? To include a minor who is able to guard his Tefillin ...

We see from here that there's a certain level of da'as required for your particular examples. If your crazy person is able to wrap himself in a Tallis, go for it. But if he has the mentality of a 6-month old, he's more likely to choke himself on the strings.

Comment: `Thus, it would seem that they wouldn't be accomplishing anything by putting on Tefillin and Tzitzis. ` How does one follow from the other? The OP seems to be asking about some mystical benefit to their soul.

Comment: I thought I made that clear at the end. Since a shoteh doesn't have da'as, he can't fulfill mitzvos, and so even if he does the action, he won't get any schar for it. (Reading "mystical benefit" as "schar in Olam HaBa.")

Comment: The end does not answer the question either. Arachin, just says that one is not _mechuyav_ in the mitzvah. It does not address, whether there is a _kiyyum mitzvah_ nonetheless, it certainly does not address whether there is heavenly reward, and it certainly certainly does not address whether there is any mystical benefit to the soul.

Comment: But it makes clear that you need a certain level of da'as to perform the mitzvah; otherwise, why should any Katan be mechuyav?

Answer (score -1):

[*Arachin* 2b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arakhin.2b.19?lang=he):

> **הכל** חייבין בציצית לאיתויי מאי לאיתויי קטן היודע להתעטף דתניא קטן היודע להתעטף חייב בציצית **הכל** חייבין בתפילין לאיתויי מאי לאיתויי קטן היודע לשמור תפלין דתניא קטן היודע לשמור תפלין אביו לוקח לו תפלין
>
> "All are obligated in Tzitzis" - ["all"] comes to include what? To include a minor who is able to wrap ... "All are obligated in Tefillin" - ["all"] comes to include what? To include a minor who is able to guard his Tefillin ...

I realise that my learning is not on the same level as the responders here.
It seems to me that if the Torah gives an unqualified **ALL** then the question is answered and doesn't require further discussion.

Comment: You should explain where your quotation came from by specific citation.

Comment: The Gemara you quote says that the word “all” is extra and so it comes to include a specific type of person - a child who’s able to wrap. “All” is not intended to be taken as literally as you intend it to. See my answer for more information.

Comment: I’ve gone ahead and reformatted the block quotes, so that the quotes are actually in the block and so that the word “blockquote” doesn’t actually appear in this post.

Comment: I am merely taking the quotation cited by @DanielF above.

Comment: There in nothing in the Halacha quoted that even remotely refers to da'as. I would think that you would give the benefit of the doubt positively and NOT negatively.